# Getting a subroutine to return a pointer referencing an array and then dereferencing it in main (in C)

Tags: arrays, pointers, integration, montecarlo

Hiya im trying to write a code for basic 1D Monte-Carlo integration.  To do so I need a list of pseudo-random numbers which I can then input into a function (stored in another subroutine).  I've given the list of random numbers a pointer but when I try to dereference it in main I get "error: incompatible types when assigning to type ‘double[11]’ from type ‘double’ " .  Could anyone tell me where I'm going wrong?  My code can be found here:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <time.h>
#ifndef RAND_MAX
#define RAND_MAX 2147483648
#endif
#define N 10

double function(double x);
double* rdm(void);

void main(void)
{
   double* Random_number_list;
   int i;
   double sum = 0.0, sum2 = 0.0, X[N+1],S, Random_number_list2[N + 1];
   double F[N+1], lower, upper, avg, avg2;
   printf("Lower Bound:  ");
   scanf("%lf", &lower);
   printf("Upper Bound:  ");
   scanf("%lf", &upper);

   Random_number_list2 = *Random_number_list;

   for (i = 0; i <= N; i++) {
      X[i] = ((upper - lower)*Random_number_list2[i]) + lower;
      F[i] = function(X[i]);
      sum = sum + F[i];
      sum2 = sum2 + (F[i] * F[i]);
   }
   avg = sum / N;
   avg2 = sum2 / N;
   S = (upper - lower) * (avg + sqrt((avg2 - (avg * avg)) / N));
   printf("The Monte Carlo approximation is %lf\n", S);  
}

double function(double x)
{
   double y;
   y = sin (x);
   return y;
}

double* rdm(void)
{
   double* Random_number_list = calloc(N + 1, sizeof(double));
   int i;

   srand(time(NULL));
   for (i = 1; i <= N; i++) {
      Random_number_list[i] = (float) rand() / (float) RAND_MAX;
   }
   return Random_number_list;
}
```

Many Thanks.  Jack Medley

Comment: Jack, it's a good idea to put your code here and assume that every other site on the internet will disappear. That way, when pastebin does disappear or starts trying to monetize their site, SO will still be useful. That's why, even if I reference Wikipedia (for example) in my answers, I'll still give a brief synopsis. I moved your code across.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given:

```
 int * a;
 int b[5];
```

then you can write:

```
 a = b;  // copying a pointer, same as a = &b[0];
```

However, you cannot write:

```
 b = a;  // b's memory is allocated, you cannot swap it out.
```

Which means, lose  `Random_number_list2`, and work with just `Random_number_list`.

You want:

```
 double* Random_number_list = rdm();
```

and later

```
 // added space, so it's clearer you're multiplying and not dereferencing.
 X[i] = ((upper - lower) * Random_number_list[i]) + lower;
```

Comment: Sorry just to clarify I want:

double* Random_number_list = rdm();

when I'm declaring in main()?